# facebook embeded post with comment

Tags: php, facebook

I created a website than can post from my website to facebook using embeded post
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts

My problem is I need to get all the comment of that certain post.
I've read about the comment plugin
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments

but i don't think that it can solve my problem since it will only give me a comment box for my website, not the comments from their post.

how do I get all the comment of that embeded post? can someone give me a link that might help? thanks.

Comment: you need to do that by using facebook graph api.

Comment: I've read about it, but i can't find the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the proper **Facebook Graph API** supplied for web developers to embed and manipulate Facebook content in their applications.

Read the specific documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api).

**EDIT:** This is the PHP SDK [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/5.0.0) and the Reference Documentation, with classes you may use to achieve what you want [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/api/5.0.0). Read it all, understand how to implement it in your project and you'll be up and running.

Comment: I've read about the facebook graph, but i can't find the solution of my problem.

Comment: That's because you're trying to use a plug-in, which is an embeddable closed-code package. I'm talking about using the API, which will allow you to work with the Facebook application-layer variables and values, thus creating your own app based on that.